# Customizing json output on mongoose

Tags: json, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am new to mongoose and mongoDB and I have been able to get json response from query through model. However, I would like to know how to have custom json output from multiple queries using mongoose. The code currently I wrote is as below.

```js
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  }
});

mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);


exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Article.find().exec(function (err, articles) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(articles);
    }
  });
};
```

And the output is

```
{
    [
        {
            "title": "Super Hero 1",
            "content": "Superman"
        },
        {
            "title": "Super Hero 2",
            "content": "Batman"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Now suppose I would like to produce json as below, how could it be done?

```
{
     "totalCount": 50, //total count of the query
     "data":  [
            {
                "title": "Super Hero 1",
                "content": "Superman"
            },
            {
                "title": "Super Hero 2",
                "content": "Batman"
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/aggregation-introduction/)** with the following pipeline:

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
    var pipeline = [
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "data": {
                    "$push": {
                        "title": "$title",
                        "content": "$content"
                    }
                },
                "totalCount": { "$sum": 1 }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0, "totalCount": 1, "data": 1
            }
        }
    ];

    Article.aggregate(pipeline).exec(function (err, articles) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(articles);
        }
    });
};
```

The pipeline is structured in such a way that your first step, the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline stage tries to group the data to process them. The  **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline operator is similar to the SQL's GROUP BY clause. In your case you supply the group by key with the `_id` value and a null value indicates you are grouping all the documents in the collection.

Similarly in SQL, you can't use GROUP BY unless you use any of the aggregation functions. The same way, you have to use an aggregation function in MongoDB as well. In this case you need the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** operator to create the `data` array. The other field `totalCount` is then accumulated using the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** operator.

The final step using the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operator involves altering the properties of your final document so that you remove the _id field.

Comment: great explanation. Will dive more on the aggregation framework. Thanks very much.

Comment: @stackdisplay No worries, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to structure a response this would be the easiest way.

```
var newResp = [{ "totalCount": listings.length , "data": listings }];

res.json(newResp);
```